# Can't change permissions on USB drive in Fedora

Tags: permissions, fedora, usb-storage

I've got a USB drive mounted (formatted with NTFS) in Fedora and I can't change the permissions on either the drive itself or anything contained within. The drive is mounted RW (the permissions are all 7**) but for some reason I can't change the permissions.

I went ahead and disabled selinux just to make sure that wasn't causing the issue, but now that it's disabled I'm at a complete loss for the problem

-Skeeter

Answer (score 0):

A `.NTFS-3G/UserMapping` file that maps UIDs to SIDs must be created on the device. See the **USER MAPPING** section of the `ntfs-3g(8)` man page for more details.